# reordering a complicated list fo data

Tags: file, list

I have a very useful script that creates this kind of (long) lists:

- The first elements are `x   y` coordinates on a 2D surface.
- The next elements are ordered so:

  - ['colorName1', 'colorName2', 'colorName3', 'colorName4']
  - [ density1, density2, density3, density4]

*

```
1 2  ['PINKwA','GB','PINK','TUwA'] [0.23816363 0.61917833 0.01219634 0.13046169]

1 3  ['PINKwA','GB','PINK','TUwA'] [0.23638376 0.6241587  0.01482295 0.12463459]

1 4  ['PINKwA','GB','PINK','TUwA'] [0.23460388 0.62913907 0.01744955 0.11880749]

1 5  ['PINKwA','GB','PINK','TUwA'] [0.23282401 0.63411944 0.02007616 0.11298039]
```

...  and it continues ... the color names are changing and also their order

```
3 55 ['OR0A','PINK','PINKwA','GB'] [0.08645924 0.09921065 0.08746096 0.72686915]

3 56 ['OR0A','PINK','PINKwA','GB'] [0.08900035 0.10021389 0.0836124  0.72717336]

3 57 ['OR0A','PINK','PINKwA','GB'] [0.09154145 0.10121713 0.07976385 0.72747757]

4 1  ['PINKwA','GB','PINK','TUwA'] [0.26096751 0.61844932 0.01412691 0.10645625]

4 2 : ['PINKwA','GB','PINK','TUwA'] [0.25918763 0.62342969 0.01675352 0.10062915]
```

...etc.

I have a list of the `colorName`'s, and a list of the `x  y` coordinates

I would like to find a solution to extract **for each color name**

- (1) the set of `x  y` coordinates at which they appear with:
- (2) the corresponding density
- (3) set the density to 0 if the `colorName` is not present

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to create a data structure  that hold color, density and coordinates as its properties.
 Now you can iterate through the list of the data structures to find your color and extract its properties easily.

About density of nameless color, you can check for color name before setting other properties.

The data structure should be something like this
Color
{
colorName
posX
posY
density
}

Comment: sounds good, what would you use to iterate through the list and generate that new data structure? I usually use codes in c++

Comment: I'm not familiar with C++, but you can create an array of the data structure and iterate through the array using for loop. Try this sitehttp://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures/.